# skimage: defining vertical shear

Tags: python, scikit-image

Python `skimage` package has a function `transform.AffineTransform()` where one of the options is `shear` which does [horizontal shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping).

Obviously, I can do a vertical shear by switching axes back and forth. This is what I do:

```
from skimage import data, transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = data.astronaut()/255

v = 0.3

tf = transform.AffineTransform(shear=-v)
img2 = transform.warp(img, tf, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')

img3 = np.swapaxes(img, 0, 1)
img3 = transform.warp(img3, tf, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')
img3 = np.swapaxes(img3, 0, 1)

plt.imshow(np.hstack([img, img2, img3]))
plt.show()
```

[image: shear]

Anyway, I am surprised there is no more direct way to define a vertical shear option... Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question (and linked page) holds the answer... as `AffineTransform` allows you to specify the transformation matrix, and your linked wiki page shows what this is, it is pretty straight forward to reduce the number of operations by directly specifying the transformation matrix, e.g.

```
from skimage import data, transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = data.astronaut()/255

v = 0.3

tf = transform.AffineTransform(shear=-v)
img2 = transform.warp(img, tf, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')

img3 = np.swapaxes(img, 0, 1)
img3 = transform.warp(img3, tf, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')
img3 = np.swapaxes(img3, 0, 1)

plt.imshow(np.hstack([img, img2, img3]))

# Using the transformation matrix directly...

tf_h = transform.AffineTransform(
    np.array([[1, 0.3, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]))
img4 = transform.warp(img, tf, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')
tf_v = transform.AffineTransform(
    np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0.3, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]))
img4 = transform.warp(img, tf_h, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')
img5 = transform.warp(img, tf_v, order=1, preserve_range=True, mode='constant')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.hstack([img, img4, img5]))

plt.show()
```

You should see two figures with the same set of images.

Comment: Thanks. When using PIL, I also specify the matrix. I was surprised there was no vertical shear parameter in scikit-image which is generally more user-friendly. I will just wait to see if someone knows of a more direct way to do it, otherwise I will give you the correct answer, it's great!

Comment: @RicardoCruz - if you look at the source (specifically here:  https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/_geometric.py#L777 ) you'll see that at least as far as AffineTransform is concerned, it definitely only supports horizontal shear.

Comment: @RicardoCruz: Also be aware that there is a little controversy about the `shear` argument at the moment: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3239 - you might want to stick to defining the transformation matrix for now anyway!

Comment: Thank you for the heads up!